# What are the good bicycles available in India

Tags: road-bike

I want to start cycling on weekend around 10 KM on road. I am not sure which bicycle would be best for me ? I do not want to invest much amount in it.

I am in India . Can anyone suggest a good bicycle which I should buy ? It should be on amazon.in

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We don't really do shopping questions, you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: Borrow one first from a friend or relative.  That will give you a better idea of what kind of bike suits you, and what frame size might fit you.

Comment: For 10km if you can get on the bike, the tyres hold air, and the brakes work you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

getting a new bike might be troublesome as it is a huge investment, but here are some tips that I always give others.

1. Get to know what kind of terrain you will be riding. There are road, trails and hybrid.

This may be a very hard factor to decide, hence many of us would recommend you borrow or rent a bike and test which suits you. Road cycling are easier and can travel further and more towards training your speed. Trails are more towards pushing yourself to overcome obstacles and about having fun. Hybrid you can do both but not as great.

2. Are you willing to spend on your hobbies?

Investing in a bike is a expensive hobby, really expensive. Getting a bike that can repair easily is the most ideal. For example, you should look for bike that has parts can be found online easily. Getting a bike that is impossible to find a replacement part will give you headache as you might have to spend more or get a new bike.

I am not from India so I cant give you my opinion but if I were you, I would get a mountain bike, which has a front suspension. DO not jump to getting a full suspension immediately tho. I favour mountain bikes more as you can swap the tires for road and swap it back for mountain bike trails where u can explore more stuff. this is just my opinion, hope it helps. you can ask me if you have any questions. :)